# Converting column with category names to numeric codes in QGIS Field Calculator

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, fields-attributes, qgsexpression

I use the Field Calculator in QGIS to transform an attribute column with category names to numeric codes. I use the following expression:

```sql
CASE
    WHEN "category" = 'Foo' THEN 1
    WHEN "category" = 'Bar' THEN 2
    WHEN "category" = 'Boo' THEN 3
    WHEN "category" = 'Far' THEN 4
    /* etc. */
    ELSE 0
END
```

Is there an automatic approach using the field calculator for cases when there are lots of categories? I would expect an algorithm that iterates over all distinct values in the source field and sets the respective number in the target field in each row with automatic incrementation.

Comment: Is there a mapping for the categories from name to numeric value, or do you just want each new name to get the next available number?

Comment: In this particular case there is no mapping and the next available number is fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a long list of values and want to avoid adding each one manually, create an array of all unique values with [`concatenate_unique()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html?highlight=concatenate_unique#concatenate-unique) and [`string_to_array()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html?highlight=concatenate_unique#string-to-array). For each field than check at which position (index) in the array it is listed with [`array_find()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html?highlight=concatenate_unique#array-find). The whole expression looks like this:

```
array_find(
    string_to_array( 
        concatenate_unique (category,concatenator:=',')
    ),
    category
)+1
```

---

*This returns the category code in the order the values appear for the first time. As you have an array, it is easy to sort it in other ways, e.g. alphabetically, adding a `array_sort()` function that encloses the `string_to_array()` part.*

Screenshot: the expression from above in action:
[image]

Comment: Thank you. Successfully tested. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

Try the [`map()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#map) in combination with the [`map_get()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#map-get) and [`coalesce()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#coalesce):

```
coalesce(map_get(map('Foo',1,'Bar',2,'Boo',3,'Far',4), "category"), 0)
```

Comment: Thank you. Successfully tested. This is much simpler than my basic solution using CASE WHEN ... THEN. However, it is still not dynamic, right? For many categories it would still by a lot of typing work.